# SQL database creation error

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I am using `-uroot` user to get log in and then I am passing command

`mysql -u abc -p -e "CREATE DATABASE drupal CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";`

but I get the error

> "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysql -u abc -p -e "CREATE DATABASE drupal
>   CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_gener' at line 1".

Not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

First connect to mysql

mysql -u abc -p

then run command

CREATE DATABASE drupal CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

Comment: The error on doing first command is "option '-e' requires an argument".

Comment: just connect using  "mysql -u root -p"     .